# How to use the replace function to replace "specific" values to another? QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-2.18

This question is actually similar to another question I had asked, but this is more a response question, since I am limited to only one question per topic. **SO PLEASE READ THIS FULLY.**

"[Using replace function to replace value to one of value map using QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233943/using-replace-function-to-replace-value-to-one-of-value-map-using-qgis-field-cal)."

Also this problem I underfound is not related to the situation I asked that question in. The problem is that the replace function also changes the text that is has in "common" of the field value I want to replace.

I discovered a new problem with the replace function and that is it also changes the text of value's that is "common text".

Let say I have I want to change the text '2015', '2016' and '2017' to 'n.v.t.'. This works great with the replace function, however there is another text called VJ2015. When I execute the 2015 replace command it also changes this to  'vjNULL'. Again not what I want, since I only wanted that "specefic text value" to be changed not the text that is "common" with other value's. So here is my case expresion':

replace("VJ/NJ (LC)", '2013' and '2014' and '2015', NULL)

I know that programs like Excel and others have "Identical letter option", I suspect that there is a way for QGIS to turn this option on.

I also understand that "" stands for column and '' stands for the value, so I suspect I need to type some specific special character to "Indenitical on" but I do not know which. So what do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to replace values which **only** contain '2015', '2016' and '2017', you could use a `CASE` statement:

```
CASE
WHEN "fieldName" in ('2015', '2016', '2017') 
THEN 'n.v.t' 
ELSE "fieldName"
END
```

This will not affect values which contain the values you specify (i.e. `VJ2015` will remain the same and will not be changed to `n.v.t`)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
CASE  
WHEN  "VJ/NJ (LC)"  not like 'VJ2015'  
THEN  replace("VJ/NJ (LC)", '2013' and '2014' and '2015', NULL)  
END
```